# Which database to use for game analytics?

Tags: analytics, hbase, hive

We're building an app that will have a number of games. Kids will learn Math as they play these games. All the user profile data, game data and lessons/ questions data are all being stored in the app and will sync to a MySQL database on the server side.

There also tons of events data that we would like to capture, analyze and improve our game. These events could be the start of a lesson, touching a game object, choosing the correct game object but targeting it wrongly, answering correctly but got timed out and so on. We expect this to be 100s of rows for each game that the kids plays. Also the data stored will be dependent on the type of event.

The database should allow us to analyze the data and answer questions like which games are tough on kids, which lessons are too easy for kids, are kids from some countries finding some of the lessons to be tough, how long are each of these games able to hold the attention of the kid and so on.

Which database would allow us to store so many different types of events, scale to millions of rows a day and allow for all these kinds of analysis? Given the changing nature of the data model, NoSQL seems to be an obvious choice. But which one would allow us to do all these analysis. Or should we go with Hadoop / Hive?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can do this using Hadoop/Hive, but you won't get real time performance as Hive is best suited for batch processing kinda stuff. Hbase would be a better choice in such a scenario. You could create OLAP datacube kinda thing whose dimensions could be the info specified by you, like session info, info about each kid etc etc. Or you could serialize all of this information as JSON objects and then store them in Hbase cells. You could also store each of these events in individual cells, but that would consume unnecessary space and won't be that efficient while fetching the data back.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Real Time Querying is not a requirement for us. Would Hive allow for arbitrary data models? If not how tough would it be to keep adding / changing data models.

Comment: How much arbitrary?Could you please be a bit more descriptive?Perhaps an example scenario...

Comment: Thanks @Tariq. 

For e.g. now we store the fact that the kid has touched a ball. Later we might want to store the fact that he touched it at point (x,y) and then later we might want to store the angle at which he swiped it. We might want to store some other event which has some totally different data like he used a helper object to get this particular object and the data to be stored for that event could be very different from the above example.

Comment: Thanks for the info @buehler. Hhbase seems to be a better choice in such a situation as you can easily keep on adding rows and columns as new data comes.